# How can I get the iOS Files app present in the MacOS Finder's iPhone Files tab?

Tags: iphone, finder, files.app

When navigating to my iPhone from the MacOS Finder sidebar I only see various apps being displayed. I know I have many more files on my iPhone from files downloaded off Safari that I've placed in the "`On My iPhone`" storage. How can I see my ***On My iPhone/Documents*** folder from MacOS Finder?
[image: iPhone on MacOS Finder App]

[image: iOS Files app]

Comment: I just confirmed that all 35 files listed in the Acrobot app show up in MacOS. It's the Documents folder with 130 items I can't figure out how to bring up in MacOS Finder.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to access this from your computer

Comment: You can AirDrop the files or use iCloud Drive to sync them over

Answer (score 5):

The only way around this that I have found is by downloading Google Chrome on my iPhone and manually moving the entire "On My Phone" folder into the newly created Chrome folder and then accessing them from that folder in the Files tab in Finder with my iPhone connected to my MacBook.

It is absolutely ridiculous that this is seemingly the easiest way to do this.

It is important to note that I wasn't able to copy files from this folder directly to an external hard drive, I had to first move them to my computer then to the external drive. So, rather than being able to natively access the local files on an iPhone from a Mac and save them to an external hard drive you have to move them to a 3rd party's folder in files, then copy, not move, them from the 3rd party folder in Finder to a local folder on your Mac.  Then finally move them from there to an external hard drive.

Needless to say that this is not a quick process if you have a large folder on your iPhone.

I'm not sure if you are still looking for a workaround like this, but since I came across this while searching for a workaround myself, I wanted to share my experience for anybody who may also be looking for help.

Hopefully Apple realizes how silly it is to not allow people to access these files natively and resolve this in future updates, I would recommend anybody that comes across this issue to leave feedback on [Apple’s Support Site](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone/)

Comment: I've been learning the intricacies of AirDrop and been mystified of late how it has this bizarre spread of timestamps that can occur to your files https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/451057/277307. I'm working on calculating a percentage of image files that have variant timestamps and try to roughly characterize how much variance can be found from an iPhone.